# Using Xcode for the first time - Unable to build w/o error

Tags: xcode

I just cloned this repo https://github.com/azamsharp/SwiftUIHealthKit  to try and get familiar with Swift and Healthkit but I can't build the project. I'm not sure what direction to go in at the moment.

Im getting two errors

- Could not initialize core
- /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVSimulator.platform:1:1: unknown platform 'appletvos' referenced as corresponding platform of 'appletvsimulator'

I tried removing the appletv simulator but there aren't any listed simulators/devices currently.

My Xcode version is 13.3.1.

Answer (score 0):

Instructions:

1. Download the zip from GitHub. Unzip it. Open the folder *SwiftUIHealthKit-master*.
2. Double-click *JustWalking.xcodeproj*. Xcode opens. Elect to trust and open if needed.
3. Choose Product > Scheme > Just Walking (iOS).
4. Choose Product > Destination > [any simulator]. If you have no simulators, go to the Devices and Simulators window and make one first in the Simulators tab.
5. Choose Product > Run.

Comment: im getting the same error messages in response this procedure

Comment: I can't explain that, sorry. I enacted the whole thing exactly as stated. Perhaps you have a bad Xcode installation but that's just a guess.